# Oracle ODI / Java - Active Directory connection trouble

Tags: java, oracle, active-directory

I want Oracle Data Integrator 10.1.3 to be able to connect to Active Directory running on a Windows 2003.

I'm using SnpsLdapDriver but so far I'm dead unable to make it work.

I keep getting error 52e : Insufficient Credentials. I tried every possible possible way I could - locking my account numerous times- and just nothing but errors.

> jdbc:snps:ldap?ldap_url=ldap://128.1.1.121:389/DC=mydc,DC=int??base?(objectClass=*)&ldap_password='encrypted_password_through_snpsldapo.jar'

I tried everything I could find on google....

HELP ????
TIA

Answer (score 0):

52e is the LDAP error code indicating either an invalid user principal or invalid user password.